# Get found value from match (regex)

Tags: javascript, regex

Need to get fruit names from a string. The string could have 2 possible way:

```
'fruit orange (some text)' or 'fr. orange (some text)'
```

I'm using following code:

```
match(/fruit (.*) \(|fr. (.*) \(|/i)
```

The problem is that in the first case I get an array with 'orange' on 1 position and in the second case 'orange' is on 2 positions.

What's the best way to get found value (fruit name) no matter which case was used to find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a capturing group. First match `fr` with an optional part which matches a dot or `uit`. then match a whitespace character `\s` followed by capturing in a group not a whitespace character `\S+`

[`^fr(?:\.|uit)\s(\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/RBFxUT/2)

Or use a broader approach:

[`^\S+\s(\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/RBFxUT/1/)

Then you can use a destructuring assignment to get the value from `String#match`:

```js
let re = /^fr(?:\.|uit)\s(\S+)/i

let str1 = 'fruit orange (some text)'

let str2 = 'fr. orange (some text)'

let [,match1] = str1.match(re) // get str1.match(re)[1] while discarding str1.match(re)[0]

let [,match2] = str2.match(re)

console.log(match1)

console.log(match2)
```

Comment: great answer! thanx a lot!

Comment: @Luca Thanks for adding a demo!

Comment: Sure thing, wanted to try this kind of statement out for a while now and didn't believe that it was worth an entire answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that every time you'll have this format of string and if you don't want to use `regex`, this is the solution for you:

```js
var str1 = 'fruit orange (some text)'
var str2 = 'fr. mango (some text)'

fruitFinder = str => str.split(' ')[1]

console.log(fruitFinder(str1));
console.log(fruitFinder(str2));
```